# How to fix ngFor/ngIf else doesn't work in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

here's the code:

```
<div *ngFor="let app of application$ | async;">
  <div *ngIf="app.length > 0; else noResults">
    <li>{{app.id}}</li>
  </div>

  <ng-template #noResults>
    No Results
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

***TS***

```
application$ = new BehaviorSubject([]);

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const arr = new Array();
    const data = [{
      id: 'room1',
      name: 'Room 1'
    },{
      id: 'room2',
      name: 'Room 2'
    },{
      id: 'room3',
      name: 'Room 3'
    }];

    this.application$.next(data);

  }
```

how to fix the else on ngFor, it when there's no data it doesn't go in noResults.
I also tried this.

***HTML***

```
<div *ngIf="application$ | async as app">
  <div *ngIf="app.length !== 0; else noResults">
    <div *ngFor="let data of app;let i = index;">
      {{ data.name }}
    </div>
  </div>
  <ng-template #noResults>
    No Results
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

it same error it doesn't display the noReuslts when there's no data

Comment: you wrote wrong name write noResults for else condition `<div *ngIf="app.length !== 0; else noResults">`

Comment: Once you fix the typo, the second version works. The first version _cannot_ work because, being nested in the `*ngFor`, the `*ngIf` will never be evaluated until its condition has already become false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML should look like this

```
<div *ngFor="let app of application$ | async;">
    <li>{{app.id}}</li>
</div>
<div *ngIf="(application$ | async).length === 0">No Results</div>
```

Or

```
<div>
    <li *ngFor="let app of application$ | async;">{{app.id}}</li>
    <ng-container *ngIf="(application$ | async).length === 0">No Results</ng-container>
</div>
```